# Magento connect error

Tags: error, image, magento-connect, optimization

I have issue when install Image Optimizer plugins.

```
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Tiny_Compresss_Images
http://connect20.magentocommerce.com/community/Kraken_Image_Optimizer
```

and i got this error

```
community/Tiny_Compresss_Images: Encountered end of file
community/Kraken_Image_Optimizer: Encountered end of file
```

suggest me to get out from this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[It's not safe to use Magento connect for installing extension , click this link for more information.](https://www.integer-net.com/why-modules-shouldnt-be-installed-via-magento-connect-manager/)

in the worst case, if you want immediate solution , Alternatively you can install the extension through FTP (like FileZilla). You can paste the extension key [in this unofficial link](http://freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php) and you can download the extension files. Let me know if you find any problems in this.

**Note** : As this is unofficial 3rd party site, there is no guarantee about security. but i tested many extensions, i did't faced any security problems....